# Angular js : How to access $state current page name and params in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have multiple pages those I want to change as per states
I am using ui-routes for managing routing.
I want to access $state.current.name in html.

`<div ng-repeat="que in questions.Cars">`

I want to change dynamically as below
`<div ng-repeat="que in questions.$state.current.name">`
So that I could traverse page wise questions.

Plunker for complete code http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Comment: Do it in controller as `$scope.something = $state.current.name` and then use that variable in html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the `$state` service in your controller. Than you can assign this service to a property on your scope.

Code:

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

Then to get the current state in your templates:

```
$state.current.name
```

To get the current state and params in your templates use `$state.includes(stateName [, params])`:

```
$state.includes('state.name', {id: 1}); // returns true
```

Comment: I want make it accessible throughout all the controls and html. how can i access in index.html.

Comment: please see my plunker link

Comment: Except index.php where you made changes?

Comment: can we add $scope.$state = $state; in .run method

Comment: `$scope.$state = $state;` added in autoQuoteCtrl, and that makes `$state` variable available in template..

Comment: Is it possible to access like <div ng-repeat="que in questions.$state.current.name">  when state changes automatically loop que will be changed.

Comment: Also the directive questionDir now receive a variable named `state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117405/discussion-between-greatym-com-and-yosvel-quintero).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$state` to be available in **all** directives you can add it to `$rootScope` in `run` method. It will be inherited by all child scopes and will be accessible from all templates,

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```